# Is there a way to use ex mode similar to ed, with append only lines and all curses like features disabled?

Tags: ex-mode

I'd like to use ex similar to how ed behaves on an old teleprinter,
so without ANSI Control sequences and CRT manipulations.

This way it would be easier to interact with it from a Braille terminal,
because one doesn't have to search for the changes that were made in the whole screen,
but can instead just read the appended lines.

I've searched for an option flag, but I couldn't find one.
Can it maybe achieved by setting the right terminal type in the vim configuration?
Or does one maybe have to change the terminal emulation itself?

To be more specific.
I'm well aware of ex/vi -e/Q, however by default this mode still performs ANSI escape sequences that operate on the screen result in place. For example when hitting enter the new lines appear above the bottom-most row.

Afaik this happens by vim removing the prompt, writing the line to be printed and then doing a newline and writing a new prompt.

Ed would leave the prompt character in tact, perform the newline, print the current line, and then write a new prompt, without destroying anything already printed, and without emitting any control sequences.

I'd like vim to behave like ed, and have it emit no destructive control characters.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "ex" here. There is an "Ex mode" that does something _sort of_ like what you're talking about (e.g. the screen doesn't get updated after each command) but I'm not sure how applicable it is here. Please see `:h Ex-mode`. If that's not a complete solution maybe it's gets you part of the way...?

Comment: @BLayer there is actually an ex binary that starts vi(m) in ex mode. Perhaps that’s what you need, j-pb? (I think it’s the same as vim -E or something; check `man ex` or `man vim`)

Comment: It's `-e`. `-E` is "improved Ex mode". That's guaranteed to be there obviously while the actual "ex" (which may just be a one-liner or a symlink if vim reads `$0`) may not be present. Either way, I wasn't even considering that OP isn't aware that `ex` is still available but that could be the case, I suppose.

Comment: If none of the above helps we really need more details. You can [edit](https://vi.stackexchange.com/posts/27860/edit) your question.

Comment: I'm not sure how to be more specific. I'll try though :)

Comment: That helps. Just thinking out loud here, I feel like it wouldn't be too hard to write a filter through which ex output is piped that strips off all ANSI codes. In fact, I just googled for a  minute and there's a ton of content about this from regexes that catch all codes to tools that basically do what I mention. Now, I don't know what the result would be when doing this with ex...if it would be well formatted or a mess...but this seems like a good avenue to explore. If the output isn't too bad some additional text processing could be scripted to iron out the wrinkles.

Comment: One technical detail is you'd have to make sure there's no buffering in whatever tool/script does the filtering. That's certainly possible, maybe as simple as dropping in some strategic flush operations, but I figured I'd point this out.